# PageViewController within NavigationController within TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I got the navigation controller and tabbar controller portions working, but I'm having a hard time with the page viewcontroller.

In one of the child view controllers of the navigation child controller, I have this:

```
pageViewController = UIPageViewController(viewControllers: viewControllers)
    pageViewController!.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
```

But the page viewcontroller doesn't show up at all.

Comment: We are going to need a lot more detail to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
[self addChildViewController:viewController];
[self.view addSubview: pageViewController.view];
[pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self]
```

Comment: I forgot the self.view.addSubview. I only had self.addChildViewController.